# SqlLite in memory database slows ResultSet next

Tags: java, database, sqlite, database-performance

I'm working with latitude and longitude as index and compiled the r*tree module into the sqlite3 database to increase the performance. Further I loaded the tables into an in-memory database. The surprising result was that the ResultSet next method slows down to 25-30 ms instead of 1 ms if the data are coming from hard disk. Normally I expect 250 entry for the result set.

First a connection is set up to the memory.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

Then the tables are copied from the hard disk into the memory:

```
Statement s = connection.createStatement(); 
s.execute("ATTACH 'myDB.db' AS fs");
s.executeUpdate("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE coordinates USING rtree(id, min_longitude, max_longitude, min_latitude, max_latitude)");
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO coordinates (id, min_longitude, max_longitude, min_latitude, max_latitude)
SELECT id, min_longitude, max_longitude, min_latitude, max_latitude FROM fs.coordinates");
s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE locations AS SELECT * from fs.locations");
s.execute("DETACH DATABASE fs");
```

The last step is query the database and copy the result into an object.

```
final String sql = "SELECT * FROM locations, coordinates WHERE (locations.id = coordinates.id) AND ((min_latitude >= ? AND max_latitude <= ?) AND (min_longitude >= ? AND max_longitude <= ?))";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
// calculate bounding rec and fullfil sql statement. 
Result rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
   // copy the stuff here
}
```

I tried some stuff like the connection should be "read only" or using TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and CONCUR_READ_ONLY or increasing the fetch size to perform the result set but `rs.next()` stays unimpressed.

Does anybody has an idea what's happening in the memory and why `rs.next()` is so slow? How could I increase the query?

The system uses the driver sqlite-jdbc 3.7.2 from org.xerial and tomcat6.

Update: Added the database schema

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE coordinates USING rtree(
 id,
 min_latitude,
 max_latitude,
 min_longitude,
 max_longitude);

CREATE TABLE locations(
 id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 number_of_locations INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
 city_en TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 zip TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 street TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 number TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 loc_email TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 loc_phone TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 loc_fax TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
 loc_url TEXT DEFAULT NULL);
```

Comment: Show the database schema of the original database, including constraints and indexes.

Comment: I'm wondering about your question about the indexes. My understanding was that the (min_latitude, max_latitude, min_longitude, max_longitude) are a new two dimensional indexes which should increase the speed. The id is the link between both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original database, the query first looks up coordinates with the R-tree index, and then looks up matching locations with the index (implied by UNIQUE) on the `id` column, as shown by this [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output:

```sql
0|0|1|SCAN TABLE coordinates VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 2:DaBbDcBd
0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE locations USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_locations_1 (id=?)
```

In the in-memory database, the table schema has changed [because](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> A table created using CREATE TABLE AS has no PRIMARY KEY and no constraints of any kind.

This particular table now looks as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE locations(
  id INT,
  number_of_locations INT,
  city_en TEXT,
  zip TEXT,
  street TEXT,
  number TEXT,
  loc_email TEXT,
  loc_phone TEXT,
  loc_fax TEXT,
  loc_url TEXT
);
```

It is no longer possible to look up locations by ID efficiently, so the database does full table scans:

```sql
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE locations
0|1|1|SCAN TABLE coordinates VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 1:
```

When copying databases, you should always use all the original CREATE TABLE/INDEX statements.

Comment: I looks that you found an issue. Maybe you was wondering why I copy the tables in two different ways. As I tried to copy the virtual table coordinates like the second one locations I got an SQL format exception. I was thinking that this has to do with the three hidden tables "coordinates_parent coordinates_node coordinates_rowid". Copying table locations like coodinates with CREATE and INSERT leads again to this full table scan which is a not wanted side effect^^. How can I copy the tables efficiently or re-create correctly?

Comment: I don't understand; what is the problem with copying `locations` with CREATE/INSERT?

Comment: I changed my code as described by you or what I understood for the table locations. statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE locations(see above)"); statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO locations SELECT * FROM fs.locations"); but there was no change in the runtime behaviour. It looks from my point of view that maybe the virtual table is not created or the link coordinates.id == locatians.id does not work.

Comment: I took now a closer look inside this hidden tables of the rtree module. All three have an integer as primary key. Could be this the reason why it works on the hard disk but not in the memory? Is there a change to get a connection to the in-memory database for debugging?

Comment: The problem was the missing index on the `locations.id` column. Does your new `locations` table have that `UNIQUE` constraint? What is the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` was looking like your second one - a full database scan. The table was looking as you posted I missed the issue with the unique `locations.id`. Now I understand your last sentence. ^^